# Android Studio - Sqlite: get random row data using cursor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have created an Sqlite table called `"TABLE1_NAME"` which contains only one column with name car_name;

In my getdata() fucntion, I am using `"ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"` in the db query to get car name with random position, however, the result is always being stored as null.

Please note: String carname already declared as a global variable.

Here's my code:

```
public String getData()
{
    sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE1_NAME+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);

    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        carName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("car_name"));
        cursor.close();
    }
    return carName; //carname=null --> null is being stored in carname
}
```

Please guide me, where am I going wrong; Thanks.

**Here is my edited code, after incorporating all your suggestions, still the result is null:**

```
 public String getData()
{
    String carName = null;
    sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TABLE1_NAME+" ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);

    if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst() && !cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        carName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("car_name"));
        cursor.close();
    }
    return carName;
}
```

**This is how i am inserting data into the database in the first place:**

```
 public void insertCarData(String[] cars)
{
    sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    for(int i=0;i<cars.length;i++)
    {
        cv.put(TABLE_CAR_NAME,cars[i]);
    }
    sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE1_NAME,null,cv);
    sqLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

The issue may be occuring from here. Thanks.

Comment: Is the column named `car_names` or `car_name`?

Comment: BTW: Why is `carName` a global variable? There's no need for it. And if `cursor==null` or `cursor.moveToFirst()` failed you will get the last result of your query - `carName` is not initialized in that case.

Comment: try like this.. **cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("car_name")**

Comment: add this in if... **&& !cursor.isAfterLast()**

Comment: In insert data method you are writing data to database, but you have taken database instance as readable so it will not write records in table so change this sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase(); by sqLiteDatabase=this.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Why do you use a `cv.put(TABLE_CAR_NAME,cars[i]);` for inserting and a `carName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("car_name"));` for reading? You should better use `carName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_CAR_NAME));` and a `"SELECT "+TABLE_CAR_NAME+" FROM "+TABLE1_NAME+" ...`

Comment: Yes, i made the change from getReadable to getWritable in insertdata()..thanks..                                                                       Regarding getData(), when i add the line sqLiteDatabase=this.getReadableDatabase();                                          then the  error: calling database recursively, and if i remove this statement from getData() then the error: calling rawQuery on null object reference occurs...i am very confused now..my app is going nowhere

Comment: How and where do you call `getData()`?

Comment: I have already tried that earlier, always gives me minute errors, so i prefer not to make those changes, but someone plz help me reg me issue; i simply don't know what must be done

Comment: I am calling getData() from my main activity which will be printing the car name in a listview:                                                                    car_name= db.getData();

                        ArrayList<String> car_list = new ArrayList<>();
                        car_list.add(car_name);

                        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, car_list);
                        lv1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

Comment: @sam88 Same like insertCarData method you need to close database after if loop in getData method also